# Brand new to Java I am attempting to write code for a filled in diamond in eclipse

Tags: nested-loops, shapes

**Updated to include what I would like and what I am getting**
I am practicing Java and continuously get stuck on nested loops. I am trying to complete some of the easier shapes and code for beginners but cannot get past this diamond.
I have been successful in creating the shape but I cannot fill it in. When I do get the shape filled in all my rows and columns are filled as well. Help assistance with where I am going wrong is greatly appreciated.

import java.util.Scanner;

public class CompleteDiamond {
public static void main(String[] args) {

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        
System.out.print("Enter the length of the pattern size: ");
int size = scan.nextInt();
System.out.println();
        
for (int row=1; row <= size*2-1; row++) { //Adds rows for shape
     for (int col=1; col <= size*2-1; col++) { //Add columns for shape
        System.out.print("  ");
        if ((row <= size && col == size-row +1 || col == size+row-1) //Shape outline
        || (row >= size && col == row-size+1 || col == 2*size-(row-size+1))) 
            System.out.print("  ");
        else 
            System.out.print("# ");
                    
    }

            System.out.println();
    }   
scan.close();   

    }
}
```

Here is what I am attempting.

```
                    #
                 #  #  #
              #  #  #  #  #
           #  #  #  #  #  #  #
        #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #
     #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #
        #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  
           #  #  #  #  #  #  #  
              #  #  #  #  #  
                 #  #  #
                    #
```

Here is what I getting
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRTR6.png)

Comment: _Help assistance_ is hardly possible if you don't state how your _diamond_ is supposed to look - it must be quite strange if it has spaces within.

Comment: My apologizes I am still very new to java and understanding how to ask for help. I have updated my post. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your program is mostly good, except for two issues.

- You swapped the `print("  ")` and `print("# ")`.
- As you wrote, you correctly determined the shape outline. In order to fill the shape, you just have to change the condition for printing the first and last `#`  to the effect that it prints it in all columns in between - `col == first || col == last` becomes `col >= first && col <= last`.

  ```
          if (row <= size && col >= size-row+1 && col <= size+row-1 // Shape
           || row >= size && col >= row-size+1 && col <= 2*size-(row-size+1))
  ```

Comment: Okay I think I understand. I was using the "||" symbol which means "or" so it was creating my outline while filling in each column. Switching the "||" to the "&&" which means "and" combines the conditions instead of separating them. Changing some of the "><" symbols determines the inside and outside of the shape and thus fills in my shape. Reversing where my "#" and " " are gives me the correct fill in.